# Using Twilio api how to send the verification code as sms

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twilio

I am using twillio api to send sms from my application . Its working fine . But I need to send the verification code as sms to verify his phone number and then need to submit registration from in my rails project.

Can any one please provide the sample example using twilio to verify the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of Twilio

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'

account_sid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
auth_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

from = '+441702806101' # Your Twilio number

friends = {
'+447908232434' => 'David'
}
friends.each do |key, value|
  client.account.sms.messages.create(
    :from => from,
    :to => key,
    :body => "#{value} you are working 30/04/2013 - CX1"
  ) 
  puts "Sent message to #{value}"
end
```

See a code complete tutorial in Ruby:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/account-verification/ruby/rails

Hope this helps